# How to catch the response in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
</html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_to_me.json?&callback=?',
            success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {

        }
        });

</script>
</html>
```

I know that this urls gives me when I hit this url on browser.:

```
{
error: "Could not authenticate you."
request: "/1/statuses/retweeted_to_me.json"
}
```

I want to catch the same thing on my ajax call above. Now `alert(data)` is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax-call. Then you can use:

```
alert(data.error);
```

Or, if it ends up in the error function:

```
error: function(req, err) {
   alert(req.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `alert(data);` to the `error:` handling function and it should show since you are recieving an error.